# Is $\int^x \cos \frac1t$ differentiable at zero?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

From Spivak's *Calculus*, 4th ed., exc 14-20:

> Let  $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \cos \frac1x, & x\neq 0\\ 0, &x=0.
>  \end{cases}$$  Is the function $\int_0^xf$ differentiable at zero?

I'm having trouble with this one; I'm sure I'm just missing something easy.

We seek

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac1h \int_0^h \cos\frac1\xi d\xi.$$

A crude estimation tells us that $\frac1h \int_0^h \cos\frac1\xi d\xi$ is between $-1$ and $1$.

Intuitively, it seems that $\int_0^h\cos\frac1\xi d\xi$ is going to zero like $h$.

I considered changing variables (although Spivak has not yet introduced this technique, so it shouldn't be necessary) to

$$\frac1h \int_{1/h}^\infty \frac{1}{u^2} \cos u,$$

but that didn't really help.

Comment: Perhaps integration by parts?
$$
\int_0^h \cos(1/t)\,dt = [t \cos (1/t)]_0^h - \int_0^h (1/t)\sin(1/t)\,dt
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without that substitution, we can note that

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} -x^2\sin \frac{1}{x} &, x \neq 0 \\ \quad 0 &, x = 0\end{cases}$$

is differentiable everywhere, with $g'(0) = 0$ and

$$g'(x) = \cos \frac{1}{x} -2x\sin\frac{1}{x}$$

for $x\neq 0$. So

$$\int_0^h \cos \frac{1}{\xi}\,d\xi = \int_0^h g'(\xi) + 2\xi\sin \frac{1}{\xi}\,d\xi = g(h) + 2\int_0^h \xi\sin \frac{1}{\xi}\,d\xi.$$

Now it is easy to see that

$$\frac{1}{h} \int_0^h \cos \frac{1}{\xi}\,d\xi = \frac{g(h)}{h} + \frac{2}{h}\int_0^h \xi\sin \frac{1}{\xi}\,d\xi$$

tends to $0$ for $h\to 0$ by the mean value theorem for integrals, since the integrand of the remaining integral is bounded by $\lvert h\rvert$ in absolute value.

---

The substitution $u = \frac{1}{\xi}$ leads to

$$\frac{1}{h} \int_{1/h}^\infty \frac{\cos u}{u^2}\,du,$$

and we can get further with an integration by parts:

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b \frac{\cos u}{u^2}\,du &= \left[\frac{\sin u}{u^2}\right]_a^b + 2\int_a^b \frac{\sin u}{u^3}\,du\\
&= \frac{\sin b}{b^2} - \frac{\sin a}{a^2} + 2\int_a^b \frac{\sin u}{u^3}\,du.\tag{1}
\end{align}$$

We can estimate the remaining integral

$$\left\lvert 2\int_a^b \frac{\sin u}{u^3}\,du\right\rvert \leqslant 2\int_a^\infty \frac{du}{u^3} = \frac{1}{a^2}.$$

So we find

$$\left\lvert \frac{1}{h} \int_0^h \cos \frac{1}{\xi} \,d\xi\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{h}\left(\frac{2}{1/h^2} + \frac{1}{1/h^2}\right) \leqslant 3h$$

for $h > 0$. The case $h < 0$ is symmetric, so we see that the integral $F$ of $f$ is differentiable in $0$ with $F'(0) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As for the way he wants it done, the hint Spivak gives is to "stare at page 179", on which are discussed the properties of the continuity and differentiability of $x^n\cos(1/x)$. I wonder what he could mean.

Comment: Doesn't give me an idea, unfortunately. Directly integrating by parts also leads nowhere, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think I got it, see updated answer.

Comment: You're right! I just came to the same conclusion, with the help of your and Omnomnom's thoughts. It's a cool way to do it.

Comment: It is indeed. A pity that one has problems to see it when one is so used to substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

This is much the same as Daniel's answer, but I wanted to write it up in a slightly different way, mostly for my own satisfaction:

On page 179, it is observed that the function 
$$\phi: x\mapsto \begin{cases}x^2\sin\frac1x, & x\neq 0\\0,& x=0 \end{cases}$$
is differentiable everywhere, with derivative
$$\phi': x\mapsto \begin{cases} 2x \sin \frac1x - \cos\frac1x, & x\neq0 \\0,&x=0. \end{cases}$$

The reader might attempt to integrate both sides, and guess that an antiderivative for our function $f$ is
$$g:x\mapsto -\phi(x) + \int_0^x 2\xi \sin\frac1\xi d\xi,$$ 
as can be checked by differentiating. (I claim the right-hand term has derivative zero at $x=0$.) Since $g'=f$ everywhere, $\int_0^hf = g(h)-g(0)$. Now 
$$\frac1h \int_0^h f = \frac1h [-\phi(\xi)]_0^h +\frac1h \int_0^h 2\xi\sin\frac1\xi d\xi\\
=\frac1h \left( h^2 \sin\frac1h \right) + \frac1h \int_0^h 2\xi\sin\frac1\xi d\xi.$$

Both terms go to zero by the fact that $|\sin|\leq 1$.